# Vertically Centering divs within a parent div with CSS

Tags: css

I have a parent div, and inside there are multiple divs that I want centered vertically.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="picBox">
        <img src="imageurl">
    </div>

    <div id="lines">
        Line 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Line2
    </div>

    <div id="other">
        Right side text
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I have set to

```
#main {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#picBox {
    height: 90px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#picBox img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#lines {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
}
#other {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background-color: #6666DD;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I can't seem to get the divs within the main div to center vertically, with the exception of the first 'picBox' div.

Is there a way to vertically center the other divs as well?

Here's my jfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ffda7ua/2/

Comment: if you are going to use float, then you might as well remove the `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
#main {
    ... //Keep your other rules
    position: relative;
}
#main div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

And handle your other positioning with `left: whatever`.

## [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ffda7ua/4/)

Comment: Thanks josh, that works for me.  Only minor problem is browser support for transform.  I ended up just using a <table> instead of only using divs to ensure it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use flex-box to align it, using a class like this one on the parent:

```
.flex-center-center{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;    
    align-items: center;
}
```